# El modo debug en intellij idea se para al iniciar un Jframe

Tags: intellij-idea, depuración

Hice un proyecto con IntelliJ en el que se abre un Jframe para insertar datos en textareas, con checkbox, etc. Estoy intentando hacer debug por un método que me devuelve falso constantemente. En cuanto se abre la interfaz gráfica e inserto datos, el debug se para y queda el programa en ejecución normal sin poder ver en qué falla el metodo.
En Eclipse esto no me pasaba.Iniciaba debug, se abría la interfaz gráfica, insertaba los datos, daba al botón que tengo configurado para ejecutar y obtener las variables, y el modo debug continuaba permitiendome ver si todo se habia asignado correctamente.
¿Hay alguna configuración específica para esto en IntelliJ? ¿Es posible que el problema está en haber sacado el método

```
eventqueue.invokelater(new runnable()
```

a mi clase de test con el método main() en vez de dejarlo donde se genera por defecto (clase que extiende de Jframe) ?
Como digo, en Eclipse funcionaba bien

Answer (score 0):

Nada, finalmente dando debug en el main() y seguidamente step into, lo he conseguido. En un inicio haciendo lo mismo no funcionaba asi.
O se iniciaba la gui y paraba el debug o hacia debug pero sin tener en cuenta la gui.
El step into parece que fué la solución